# Can I map one object type to another dynamically by return type?

Tags: typescript, lodash

I would like to achieve dynamic value mapping from:

```
type A = { name: string; age: number; dictionary: { type: 'Dictionary'; id: string; name: string } }
```

to:

```
type B = { name: string, age: number; dictionary: { label: string; value: string } }
```

using lodash mapValues:

```
const mapData = (data) => {
  if (!data) { return {} }

  return mapValues(data, cb)
}
```

where callback refers to:

```
const cb = (value: string | boolean | number | null | Dictionary) => {
  if (typeof fieldValue === 'string') {
    return fieldValue as string;
  }
  if (typeof fieldValue === 'boolean') {
    return fieldValue as boolean;
  }
  if (typeof fieldValue === 'number') {
    return fieldValue as number;
  }
  if (fieldValue === null) {
    return null;
  }

  if (has(fieldValue, 'type')) {
    return mapDictionary(fieldValue)
  }
}
```

```
const mapDictionary = ({ id, name }: Dictionary) => ({ label: name, value: id })
```

The problem:
mapValues does not recognize whats going in/out.

Can I do it easier to do the mapping in generic way that it will infere keys of original input object but with new value type after mapping?

Comment: Have you looked into [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html)? Never used them myself but the last section makes it seem like it could be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using mapped types, conditional types and `infer` keyword.

```
type MyType = { name: string; age: number; dictionary: { type: 'Dictionary'; id: string; name: string } }

type MyTypeMoreSpecific = { name: string; age: number; dictionary: { type: 'Dictionary'; id: 'static id'; name: 'static name' } }

type Convert<T extends {}> = {
    [key in keyof T]: ConvertField<T[key]>
}

type ConvertField<T> = T extends (string | number | boolean | null) 
    ? T 
    : T extends {type: string, id: infer ID, name: infer NAME} 
        ? {label: NAME, value: ID}
        : never;

type MyTypeConverted = Convert<MyType>;
type MyTypeMoreSpecificConverted = Convert<MyTypeMoreSpecific>;
```

You can check this code on [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiAq5oF4oG8oDsCGBbCAXFAM7ABOAlpgOYDcU21hWArrgEYRn0AmFAxsAoB7HGRBEMoSEQDkAEQFDR2cbPoUeRUpRr0c+beSrUoAX3MBYAFA3p0OIkgxhZCAGVI-CgDMBUVAwDZh0TekZmTDZObig+QRExCXQoezlFBJU1DS0oWVJsIX4oTXUsPGZ84EL-YNlzK1treygAYVEANy5gAB54KAgAD2AITB5idDMAPgD0GygFqABtAGsIEBLMKDWQYR8oeABdInbMLrJgADEKCAAbHj7V9cOpmzMbOyQ2zu7ru4f4DNUP0hiMxhMABShGhQAA+rA4XDhUHYwmEtwg2C28Kit1uAEooPNFgB+A5E6yLKBEEHDUbjdBpEjGGgAGhKuSoPiRAEl5OzgkQuUiAHIAQRgAFELMSqQsyWhbthOLciOKpeyOthbixmHz3pS5QsiJgIOdaB9ml9HEhTucRjxZnbuj0bZApharZBYAgkC43J4IN4-PxnRcII7UGHem6IP6PF5fAIPUA). When you hover over converted type you'll see details about it.

How this works: `Convert<T>` accepts an object type and returns new mapped object type where for each key of original object we have `ConvertField<T>` where we pass original value. `ConvertField<T>` in turn checks if passed type is either string, number, boolean or null and if so - return it as is. If passed argument is object of shape `{type: string, id: <something>, name: <something>}` then we 'extract' types of `id` and `name` and return new type with fields `label` and `value` using previously extracted types. If argument has some other type (e.g. object of different shape), `ConvertField` will return `never` which is how you indicate error in TS type.

Conditional types (especially with `infer`) might be a bit tricky if you didn't use it before, so I'd recommend to check [this chapter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) from TypeScript handbook if needed.